# How to show that there exists a scalar $\lambda$ so that $A = \lambda I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, $V \ne \{ 0 \}$ and $A\in L(V)$ an operator which commutes with every operator from $L(V)$. Show that there is a scalar $\lambda$ so that the following applies: $A = \lambda I$.

$L(V)$ = The set of all linear mappings (linear operators) from V to V

If $B\in L(V)$ is arbitrary and if I understood the assignment correctly, this would mean $AB = BA \implies AB - BA = 0 $

I believe, a matrix representation of the linear operators would apply here but I don't have any idea what to do here.

**EDIT (Hint by Jared)**

I tried to examine it on 5x5 matrices:  [example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PHYx.png), [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iAnt.png).

For example, for:
$\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15} 
\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25}
\\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & a_{35} 
\\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & a_{45}
\\ a_{51} & a_{52} & a_{53} & a_{54} & a_{55}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{12} & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{22} & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{32} & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{42} & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{52} & 0\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15} 
\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25}
\\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & a_{35} 
\\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & a_{45}
\\ a_{51} & a_{52} & a_{53} & a_{54} & a_{55}\end{bmatrix}
 = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & a_{45}
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

which means $a_{22}=a_{44}$. 
For a 1 on the $ij$th and $ji$th position, I get 2 equations (actually 4 but 2 of them are equal to the other 2).

But I still don't understand what I can conclude from that. I reviewed older homework assignments and found the same problem but with a hint:
"Show that A has at least one eigenvalue and observe the corresponding subspace of the eigenvalue. Before that, show that every subspace of an eigenvalue of the operator $T \in L(V)$ is invariant for every operator $S \in L(V)$ which commutes with $T$."

**EDIT 2**

For $B=E_{ij}$ I conclude that $ AB=BA \implies a_{ii}=a_{jj}, a_{ij} = 0$ if $i \ne j$
(In my example, i is 2 and j is 4 so it turned out $a_{ii}=a_{22}=a_{44}=a_{jj}$)

For $B = E_{ij} + E_{ji}, AB = BA \implies a_{ii} = a_{jj},  a_{ij} = a_{ji},  a_{kl} = 0$ for $ k=l \ne i,$ and $ k=l \ne j $ and $ k\ne i \space \& \space l\ne j$ and $ k\ne j \space \& \space l\ne i$

But we can write B in a different way:
$B = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_{ij}E_{ij}$

$AB = A(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_{ij}E_{ij}) =$ associativity of matrix and scalar multiplication & distributivity over matrix addition $=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(\beta_{ij}A)E_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_{ij}(AE_{ij})$

$BA = (\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_{ij}E_{ij})A = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_{ij}E_{ij}A = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE_{ij}(A\beta_{ij}) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(E_{ij}A)\beta_{ij}$

$AB = BA \implies \beta_{ii}a_{ii} = \beta_{jj}a_{jj},  \forall i,j\in \{1, ... , n\} \space \& \space \beta_{ij}a_{ij} = 0 \space , i \ne j$

Which would give us a system of $n^2$ linear equations:
$\beta_{11}a_{11} = \beta_{11}a_{11}$
$\beta_{11}a_{11} = \beta_{22}a_{22}$
...
$\beta_{11}a_{11} = \beta_{nn}a_{nn}$

$\beta_{22}a_{22} = \beta_{11}a_{11}$
$\beta_{22}a_{22} = \beta_{22}a_{22}$
...
$\beta_{22}a_{22} = \beta_{nn}a_{nn}$

...

$\beta_{nn}a_{nn} = \beta_{11}a_{11}$
$\beta_{nn}a_{nn} = \beta_{22}a_{22}$
...
$\beta_{nn}a_{nn} = \beta_{nn}a_{nn}$

$\implies \beta_{11}a_{11} = \beta_{22}a_{22} = ... = \beta_{nn}a_{nn} = \beta a$
$\implies A = \lambda I$ for $\lambda = \beta a$

Comment: Choose any basis for $V$, and let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with a $1$ in the $ij$th position, and $0$ elsewhere.  See what the commutation relation implies about $A$ when you apply it to matrices $B=E_{ij}$ and $B=E_{ij}+E_{ji}$.

Comment: Hi Jared, thank you for your answer, I edited my post and wanted to know if your hint was intended as a help to conclude the other hint I found on the older homework assignment or do you have a different proof in mind?

Comment: Not only have you concluded that $a_{22}=a_{44}$, but also that $a_{12}=a_{32}=\ldots=a_{45}=0$.  In general, you've shown $a_{ij}=0$ if $i\ne j$ and $a_{11}=a_{22}=\ldots=a_{nn}$.  This proof is different than the one to which your hint is leading you.

Comment: I thought about it and the result can be seen in EDIT 2. For some reason, I doubt that my reasoning is correct but I may be one step further. (?)

Comment: Thanks everybody, the given link contains excellent answers so I don't have any intentions to edit this question any further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Tx=ax\implies T(Sx) = S(Tx) = a (Sx)$ and hence $Sx$ is in the $a$ eigenspace of $T$ along with $x$.

Hence if $T$ has one eigenvalue, by choosing an $S$ that maps a corresponding eigenvector to an arbitrary $y$, we see that $y$ has the same eigenvalue. Hence $T\propto I$.

Now you just need $T$ to have one eigenvalue. Lots of ways to do this. For example, choose $S$ to have the maximal $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Then $T$ must map each eigenvector to a multiple of itself, and hence has not just one but $n$ eigenvectors.

This result is essentially Schur's Lemma.

Comment: Since Jared posted only comments and you gave a very detailed answer for the second way to prove it, I decided to choose your answer as the accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_{i,j}$ be the matrix with $1$ in $i,j$ position and 0 everywhere else.
Use that $AE_{1,i}=E_{1,i}A$ to show that
$a_{1,1}=a_{i,i}$, $a_{j,1}$ for $j=2,3,\ldots,n$ and $a_{i,j}=0$ for $j\neq i$.

Comment: Jared already implied this reasoning with his hints but thank you anyway!